# Java generic, returning concrete instance issue

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Please help. I can not deal with generics. I have:
Generic interface repository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface PageBaseRepository<T extends PageBase> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {
    List<T> findAllByUserId(UUID userId);
}

@Repository
public interface StandardPageRepository extends PageBaseRepository<StandardPageEntity> {
}

@Repository
public interface BlockPageRepository extends PageBaseRepository<BlockPageEntity> {
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class PageBaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private UUID userId;
    private String content;


@Entity
public class StandardPageEntity extends PageBaseEntity {
    private String extraField;
}

@Entity
public class BlockPageEntity extends PageBaseEntity {
    private String blockPosition;
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PageRepositoryFactory {
  private final StandardPageRepository standardPageRepository;
  private final BlockPageRepository blockPageRepository;


    public <R extends PageBaseRepository<E>, E extends PageBaseEntity> R getRepository(final E entity) {
        if (entity instanceof StandardPageEntity) {
            return standardPageRepository;
        }
        if (entity instanceof BlockPageEntity) {
            return blockPageRepository;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not recognised pension object " + pensionEntity.getClass());

    }
}
```

I am getting hint in intelij:

> Incompatible types. Required: R Found:StandardPageRepository

and error in console:

> PageRepositoryFactory.java:15: error: incompatible types:
>   StandardPageRepository cannot be converted to R
>               return standardPageRepository;
>                      ^   where R,E are type-variables:
>       R extends PageBaseRepository declared in method getRepository(E)
>       E extends PageBaseEntity declared in method getRepository(E)

One thing I found out is that I can do casting, but this is ugly, compilator says it is `Unchecked cast`. And I do not wanna this warning.

Comment: `return (R) standardPageRepository;` - their is no real other way. The compiler cannot evaluate your `instanceof` check and therefore cannot know wether `standardPageRepository` is an `R`.

Comment: If you are using `instanceof` in a generic method, then you are doing something not very generic

Comment: You should probably declare the method as `<E extends PageBaseEntity> PageBaseRepository<E> getRepository(final E entity)`.

Comment: I know about cast, but this is ugly, and compilator is complying about it. What can You propose instead of `instanceof`?

Comment: Basically, you aren't giving compiler guarantees that your `E` is the `StandardPageEntity` when returning the `standardPageRepository` (yes, yes, I know). The cast is mandatory either way. Instead of the `instanceof` you can use implementation map.

Comment: @luk2302, I believe there is a JEP for that (the instanceof enhancements), but it's not coming for a while.

Comment: Your code should not even compile because there is no return value in case both ifs evaluate to false, right?

Comment: @luk2302 I respect You, so I dont just copy paste everything, but minimalist example. I have 13 sub class, this is just example. I've updated example with throw at the end.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I've tried Your method signature proposal, but this change nothing. I still need Cat, but to more concrete type.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Can You share some link or more detail about implementation map?

Comment: @masterdany88, just a dictionary of `<Class<?>, Repository<PageBase>>`, no big deal at all. Still needs a cast, there's not enough tools in Java type system at this moment to not require one.